# Website page indexing problem

Tags: google, search-engine-indexing, google-index

My blog posts are not index or shown instantly on Google once I posted, I have to request for index manually which I don't think is the best way. If I inspect the URL in live view it will be indexed by on Google will will not.
Please and solution to this. I want my post to show instantly I posted them.

Comment: Google does not instantly index all pages on the internet. The pages that are quickly indexed are from sites that have developed some authority, they have links from other sites pointing toward their site. And, they have unique content that Google considers quality; Google takes a lot of factors into consideration. The best way to get a new site, (assumption but useful to others if not directly to yourself), to be indexed quickly is to forget about Google, and focus on social media, etc to build a community or following ... Google will see the activity and decide your content is quality.

Comment: Thanks for this, I really appreciate